# Unable to Sign In to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, and when I tried to Sign In to my Microsoft Account, I get the following error:

> SP324099: Could not complete the operation.

Furthermore, my IE starts up. I tried to find solutions online, nothing worked (there was something about flushing DNS; I tried that but it didn't work).

Is anyone familiar with this error or can suggest me a way to get around this?

Comment: Worth trying [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ec53531-1ea3-40fa-9eb3-e8a41cd5eee3/sp324099-could-not-complete-the-operation-problem-in-visual-studio-2013?forum=vssetup) if this is still not resolved - looks like starting Visual Studio with `/resetuserdata` might reset some things.

Comment: I have this problem in Visual Studio 2015 RC as well. Nothing seems to get it to work.

Comment: @shawn.mek it worked for me when I reinstalled windows. Not suggesting that as a solution, just reiterating the fact that it's been almost a year with no solution.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with VS2015 (but, strangely, not with VS2013).  The advice from @Petrovich1999 did not help me, but updating IE did.  Turns out I was still running IE8 on my office workstation (I never use IE), and upgrading to IE11 allowed me to sign into Visual Studio.

Comment: I didn't have Internet Explorer installed. I had to turn on Internet Explorer in Windows Features and then upgrade to IE11.

Comment: I have win 10 with IE11 but the problem remains the same

Comment: my VS2015 says that the services are not available even if they are -- can't sign in

Comment: Updating IE to 11 did the job for me (was running IE8 before). Thanks! I think this advice saved me a ton of time.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Win10 which already has IE11. Resetting IE to it's default settings, however, **did** work.

Comment: I had this problem with VS 2015 Community, with the latest IE11, but enabling Cookies made no difference. The problem was due to a blocked MS cookie in Settings/Privacy/Sites, and after deleting the cookie I could login to VS and MSDN as usual.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed odd behavior, however easy to fix. Go to https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/view , on the right part of the page under Account header you will see link "create a free account now". Just do it then log in your Visual Studio like you have tried before. Worked for me.

Comment: For future reference: After making an account (It will ask you to make a website), the website will want to create a new project. I did not have to set up a new project online to get visual studio to work. I just created a new account, logged into VS2013, and closed my browser tab.

Comment: worked. thanks
i think some caching was creating the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Resetting IE settings solved this for me.

Found answer here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows_10/ie-11-prevents-me-from-registering-visual-studio/0f9ec16e-cc19-403c-9234-5e92ba00e276?auth=1

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the same (if not similar) error can happen if ALL cookies are blocked in internet explorer.

If you go to internet explorer's internet options under privacy, make sure that the security level on cookies is set to "Most" or lower. After that I had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, updating IE solved the VS sign-in issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/854486/vs2013-community-can-not-sign-in.html) helped me.

> Try to enable/add TLS 1.0 or configure .NET Framework to support strong cryptography to use TLS 1.2 from registry:
> For configuring to support strong cryptography > press Windows key + R > type regedit > navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319** > add a new registry entry named **SchUseStrongCrypto** > set its type to **DWORD** > set its value = **1**

After that I restarted VS2013 and were able to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the password of your Microsoft account might help. Maybe, Visual Studio does not support all special characters that are supported for the account. 
For me, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution is different.  If your network is using proxy server try this. The issue was with proxy settings.  I wanted to choose **"Automatically detect settings"**
options in LAN Settings instead of manually giving proxy server address and port

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to -> https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/view

2) Press "Create a free account now" and create one

3) Go to Visual Studio(File->Account Settings->Check for an updated Licence

It will automatically use your account you just created and update your licence

Comment: the "Create a free account now" does not exist on that link you posted

Comment: Links change all the time i guess. I answered to this post about 2 months ago :)

Comment: I guessed as much. Am trying to repair my visual studio 2015 to see if the sign in page can be bypassed

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. The solution is to create account and log in via your visual studio

Comment: I already have an account , could i not reuse the same account for login in visual studio

Comment: If you create a second account and log in with it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to activate Javascript in Internet explorer? I had the same problem, i opened IE for the first time since i used it to download chrome and it's security method was bassically to disactivate every kind of add-on so just activating "scripting" in Tools/internet options/security/custom settings made me able to log in visual studio again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IE options, select Privacy, Sites.
Check to see if you have any MS web sites that may be blocked, for me it was live.com, by allowing it the problem was solved.

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I can't sign in in Visual Studio 2013 community. Something broken. VS2013 welcome sign in page didn't work. 
The solve was to try download [VS2015 from official site](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads)

I got error when click download VS2015: I should join Dev community or purchase. I click "join" - download page was loaded. VS2013 login page starts to work on my PC.