# visual studio 2013 login error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I try to login into visual studio with my microsoft account, it just shows me this screen and won't login, and it starts making loads of mouse click sounds.

[image]

im using visual studio 2013, and im trying to upgrade after my 30 day trial buy logging into my account which has visual studio professional tied to it through dreamspark.

im not too sure what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found problem.

had to lower IE. trusted site security level

Comment: i also had to update my IE and had to follow these instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017318/unable-to-sign-in-to-visual-studio-2013