# Visual Studio Community 2013: SP324099 When Trying to Log In (With IE11)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msdn

So, after using the new quote "Free" version of Visual Studio 2013 -- ie Visual Studio Community 2013 -- for a time, I have gotten the message that my "30 day trial" has expired...

> License: 30 day trial (for evaluation purposes only)
>
> This license has expired.
>
> ! Your trial has expired. Sign in to acquire a license using an online account

Ok...so I tried to click the "Sign On" option I was given. The result? I get this message in the window that comes up:

```
Sorry, we ran into a problem
SP324099: Could not complete the operation
```

This also happens when I try the `Check for an updated license` option.

According to the answers I saw
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017318/unable-to-sign-in-to-visual-studio-2013)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419539/visual-studio-2015-rc-sp324099)
the fix was to update Internet Explorer to version 11. The only problem? I have IE11 already. I can't really find any way to fix this for Visual Studio Community 2013, and I'm not sure what to do with this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

EDIT: I am not sure if this is relevant information but I will include it in the event that it is. When the error comes up, I get an IE browser window that pops up as well. This IE browser takes me to a site with an invalid/expired certificate (that appears to still be MSDN...I hope). I continue and log in to MSDN, but it just gives me this dictionary with `{"securityToken": ["..."]}`

Is the certificate problem related to this somehow? Does this information provide a clue as to what the answer is? Thanks.

Comment: Check your system time... SSL errors and sign-on issues are often caused by incorrect date/time settings of the computer, causing the SSL handshake to fail.

Comment: @jessehouwing Good idea, I didn't think about that! Unfortunately though resynchronizing my time didn't solve my problem. Although it gave me the idea to change my system time date to be back when I initially installed VSCommunity 2013 which prevented the message from popping up. Not ideal for sure, but at least I can get some work done for the time being... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After you have attempted to refresh the "free" license, if this popup window with the error message appears, just simply click on the X in the upper right-hand corner of the window to close the popup. (Instead of attempting to sign in again.)